Differences in oar position configuration in rowing
I was watching the rowing during the Paris 2024 Olympics in which this particular race have 4 people each having one oar to control.
One thing I noticed between teams is that the configuration in terms of what side of the boat the oars were positioned differed. For example I saw the oars (from bow to stern):

Left, Right, Left, Right
Left, Left, Right, Right
Left, Right, Right, Left
... and vice-versa

Or, more visually:
        ^                    ^                    ^
[  ]====|            [  ]====|            [  ]====|
        |====[  ]    [  ]====|                    |====[  ]
[  ]====|                    |====[  ]            |====[  ]
        |====[  ]            |====[  ]    [  ]====|       
        v                    v                    v

What determines the oar configuration?

Is it based around the rowers themselves? ie the person sitting in the stroke seat is left-handed, so they have their oar out to the right (does which hand is dominant even matter...?)
Is there some perceived strategic benefit to running one configuration over another?
Does which lane you are in have an impact?
Does conditions on the course on the day have an impact?


I don't have a full answer but if you want to hit your favourite search engine, having two rowers next to each other on the same side is known as "bucket rigging".
